# phpexcel data to mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, phpexcel

I have a upload system where the users have to upload their Excel sheet and I have to store the information to MySQL database. The file has to be uploaded by the users, here I had a problem that there is not fixed structure is there.

Some of them will upload having header as and with some extra details as per required:

Name | Father Name | Date of Join | Address | Phone

--------------------------+++----------------------

Name | Father Name | Phone | Date of Join | Address

Here I am using PHPExcel lib to extract the data from Excel, it is working fine, when coming to the date it is not parsing properly and I how to loop between the columns for their formatting. 
As I am using this method as it is suggested in stackoverflow, it is formatting but for phone number also it is applying changing the data.

```
$excelDate = $cell->getValue(); // gives you a number like 44444, which is days since 1900
$stringDate = \PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($excelDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

The problem is unknown column location of date and data, how to loop and store in MySQL the exact data in database.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is that the columns may be in a different order in different Excel files. Is that correct?

Comment: exactly @alanlittle

Comment: Have you considered `$cell->getFormattedValue();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$baseDate = strtotime('1900-01-01');
$excelDate = $cell->getValue(); // gives you a number like 44444, which is days since 1900
$date = strtotime("+$excelDate day", $baseDate); //Adds the number of days to the base date
$stringDate = \PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($date, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Comment: while looping it is effecting the phone numbers also.

Comment: @bhrmalik, put a condition to see if it's `Date of Join`, use my code, otherwise, use the regular code

Comment: Are you aware that PHPExcel provides functions for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

If the file always has column headers, use an array to match them up with column numbers, something like this:

```
// Read the header row into an array
$excel1 = ['Name', 'Father Name', 'Phone', 'Date of Join', 'Address'];
$colnbr = 1;
foreach ($excel1 as $colname) {
  $columns[$colnbr++] = $colname;
}
// Process the rest of file 1

// Read the header row into an array
$excel2 = ['Name', 'Father Name', 'Date of Join', 'Address', 'Phone'];
$colnbr = 1;
foreach ($excel2 as $colname) {
  $columns[$colnbr++] = $colname;
}
// Process the rest of file 2
```

Then, while you're processing the rest of the file, use this to match up the columns you're processing with their respective database fields.

Comment: thanks for your early reply, _when coming to the date it is not parsing properly phpexcel_ as many excel file as many database table, so their is no need to match them and insert in particular table, when i am using the code it is effecting the phone numbers too.

Comment: OK, I guess I'm still not sure I understand you, let me try again: You don't know what order the columns will be in, thus the phone number gets processed as a date. Is that it?

Answer (score 0):

PHPExcel provides functions for identifying if a cell is formatted as a date or not

```
$isdate = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell);
```

(note that this will not work if you have loaded the file with readDataOnly set to true).

and for converting MS Excel DateTime stamps to unix timetamps or PHP DateTime objects

```
$unixTimestamp = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($cell->getValue());
$phpDateTimeObject = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($cell->getValue());
```

which you can then manipulate or format using PHP's on built-in functions